# Does EF code-first require navigation properties for deleting many-to-many relationships?

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have two POCOs participating in a many-to-many relationship.  "A" has a collection of "B" but there is no need for "B" to have a collection of "A".  When I delete "B" the records in the Join table are not removed.  It appears that Entity Framework code-first only deletes the Join records if there is a Navigation property.  Is this correct or is there another way?

Example:

```
public class User() { 
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role() { 
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

//... Mapping Config ...//
this.HasMany(x => x.Roles)
   .WithMany(/*can't be expressed without navigation property*/)
   .Map(m => {
      m.MapLeftKey("Users_Id");
      m.MapRightKey("Roles_Id");
      m.ToTable("UserRoleLinks");
   });

//... Deleting a Role that is in use ...//
using(var ctx = new MyDbContext()) {
    var role = ctx.Roles.Find(1);
    ctx.Roles.Remove(role);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

In this scenario, the UserRoleLinks records will be orphaned when the Role is deleted.  Mabye there is a different way to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work without any problem. Default `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention` will force EF to create junction table with relations using cascade deletes. Missing navigation property in `Role` entity has no impact on that.

So possible reasons for your problem:

- You removed mentioned convention
- You are missing cascade deletes on relations in junction table - this can for example happend when using Fluent API with existing database.

Comment: I will give this a try.  Should the cascade delete be enabled in the database and with the convention in EF?  I thought I read that enabling cascade deletes in the database would mess up when EF tries delete the join records only to find them already gone.

Comment: I can't get this to work, because of that other RC 4.1 issue where the default foreign keys are singular now.  Unless I define the WithMany as WithMany(r => r.Users) EF gets the field names wrong because it tries to use User_Id rather than Users_Id.  And I can't define the WithMany unless I have the Navigation property from the Role back to Users.

Comment: I have decided there are two questions involved here.  As for the cascade deletes, this answer applies. I enforced them in the database and that effectively solved the problem.  The other issue is that when you don't express the reciprocal "with many" collection property, EF guesses at the foreign key rather than using the one provided in the fluent expression.